# Git: SSH connection not working. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, permissions

My git SSH connection is not working. However, I've generated an SSH-key, added it to my GitHub account and the `ssh -T git@github.com` is showing success.

However, the `ssh -T *username*@github.com` command is **not** working. I think this is what is causing the permission error on the git pull action I'm trying to perform.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -T *username*@github.com` works only with real SSH servers, not Git hostings. For SSH at Git hostings always use *username* `git`. The real username at Git hostings must be used with HTTPS but not SSH.

So fix your URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
```

and pull/push.

Comment: I see. So what do you suggest I do to git pull from a my repository?

Comment: @user7431590 `git remote set-url origin git@github.com`. See the update.

Comment: I now get the error

fatal: 'git@github.com' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Did you see the full URL in the updated answer? I only provided shortened version in the comment above.

Comment: I still get the Permission denied (public key) error.

Comment: Does `ssh -T git@github.com` shows "Welcome, USER"? If it's a different user — do you have access to `USER/REPO.git`?

Comment: It shows the correct username. It's the same username as in the remote yes.

Comment: Windows? On Windows Git brings its own copy of SSH so `ssh -T git@github.com` and `git push` could use different `.ssh/` directories and different keys.